# Find out missing files between two directories (missing file names, but not extension) in Linux

Tags: linux, diff, difference

Say I have dir1/ that has 1.a 2.a 3.a 5.a and dir2/ has 1.b 2.b 3.b 4.b 5.b.

I wonder how can I ignore the extension, and find the missing file (4.b in this case).

I assume that `diff` command doesn't work as I don't see  relevant argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `basename` command to strip the basename:

```
find dir1 -type f -exec basename '{}' .a \; | sort > list1
find dir2 -type f -exec basename '{}' .b \; | sort > list2
```

Then use `diff list1 list2` to compare the two. Or maybe use `comm` instead of `diff`.

As an alternative to basename (which requires to explicitly specify `.a` and `.b`) you could also use `sed` to strip everything after the last dot:

```
ls dir1 | sed -e 's,\.[^.]*$,,' | sort > list1
ls dir2 | sed -e 's,\.[^.]*$,,' | sort > list2
```